# Can not find button. Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I have this code:

[image: HTML CODE]

Then using selenium I write this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("extra-delivery-item")).click();
```

The question is why does selenium tell me:
***no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".extra-delivery-item"***

P.S. I have already located some buttons and successfully clicked on them, everything works, except that button.

Comment: Please don't post code as image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: A shoot into the dark: On your image there are more than one element with this css class name.

Comment: Is this static HTML or are you dynamically modifying the DOM (like when using some sort of frontend framework)? Maybe you'll need some [waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/).

Comment: Just opened developer tool to search for buttons, then to click on them using Intellij idea + selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element is actually has multiple class names. So to select it according to single class name you can use XPath or CSS selector.
Like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'extra-delivery-item')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.extra-delivery-item")).click();
```

Selecting element by class name, like you tried to use

```
findElement(By.className("extra-delivery-item"))
```

means matching element with class attribute exactly matching that value, `extra-delivery-item` in this case. While the element class attribute here is `extra-delivery-item extra-delivery-item-selected`

Comment: Hello, ty for the answer, but selenium still throws exception

Comment: what exception?

Comment: Actually in the image there *is* an element with a class attribute exactly matching the value "extra-delivery-item".

Comment: As mentioned by @reporter: is that locator unique?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class,'extra-delivery-item')]"}

Comment: @Dontyoumind can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Dontyoumind maybe you missing a delay before accessing that element?

Comment: https://shop.silpo.ua/

Dunno about l10n, so under the map make one tap on the button, then on the right side one more tap. Opens menu, two blocks. I need to click on them

Comment: @Prophet Did you figure out how the interface works or you need more help?

Comment: Still didn't saw it, busy on my work. Also my boss is here :)

Comment: Ok, hope you'll have a bit of time to look at it after your workday. I appreciate your time and advice, ty (;

Comment: can you explain what is the flow there? If it will be easier for you - you can do it in Russian :)

Comment: Long story short I do these things for my pet project. This is a local store, i want to parse products. To do this i need to go to the page where they are. To achieve this I need to click buttons. So, i don't know anything about flows and how this site is built. Just need buttons xd

Comment: You didn't understand my previous question. So, I open that link. What button should I click, what element? What is after that? What is working for you and what element you could not access?

Comment: You didn't understand my previous question. So, I open that link. What button should I click, what element? What is after that? What is working for you and what element you could not access?

Comment: @Prophet Sry, had to go, imgur link with explanation: https://imgur.com/a/OHuLhRx

Comment: OK, got it. will do it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to hearing from you (;

Comment: @Prophet BRUH dunno what happened but your solution helped me!
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.extra-delivery-item")).click();
THANK YOU sooooo much

Comment: Waiting for an element to load - this is essential here as I understood. So when I tried your option the element just did not loaded, that is why click failed.

Comment: Great! Happy I could be helpful.